# Bytefield bitheader escaping its minipage?

Tags: minipage, bytefield

In a small segment of a much larger document, I'm building a poor man's two-column layout using minipages for a short run. The bitheader from the bytefield in the right column, however, seems to be escaping its minipage, and I don't understand why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[layout=letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[endianness=big]{bytefield}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Functional Unit Addresses}
This section describes\ldots

\subsubsection{{\tt 0b1000}: CTR Layer (Registers)}

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  Address    & Function (32~bit Data) \\ \hline
  \tt 0b0XX0 & Non-INT Register (\#0 -- \#3) \\
  \tt 0b1XX0 & INT Register (and wake) (\#0 -- \#3) \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\subsubsection{{\tt 0b1010}: CTR Layer (DMA)}

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  Address    & Function (32~bit Data) \\ \hline
  \tt 0b1000 & DMA Data \\
  \tt 0b1010 & {\em DMA Control Message} \\
\end{tabular}

\subsubsection{{\tt 0b1001}: DSP Layer (Registers)}

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  Address    & Function (32~bit Data) \\ \hline
  \tt 0b0000 & Reg 0: Status Register \\
  \tt 0b0010 & Reg 1: General Purpose \\
  \tt 0b0100 & Reg 2: General Purpose \\
  \tt 0b0110 & Reg 3: General Purpose \\
  \tt 0b1000 & DMA Data \\
  \tt 0b1010 & {\em DMA Control Message} \\
  \tt 0b1100 & 32 bit data for CPU (IRQ0) \\
  \tt 0b1110 & 32 bit data for CPU (IRQ1) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}

{\bf DMA Control Message}:

\bigskip
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em,bitheight=3em]{16}
  \bitheader{16-31} \\
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny TX RQ}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny RX RQ}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny DONE}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{13}{\# of words (TX RQ)}
  \\
  \bitheader{0-15} \\
  \bitbox{2}{\tiny TX Dest}
  \bitbox{14}{Start word addr}
\end{bytefield}
{\em TX Dest:} 00 DSP, 01 R-SRAM, 10 RF, 11 Imager
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

The bitheader for bits 31-16 shouldn't be in the left column...:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell `bytefield` what's the least significant bit; the two column format has nothing to do with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[layout=letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[endianness=big]{bytefield}

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em,bitheight=3em]{16}
  \bitheader[lsb=16]{16-31} \\
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny TX RQ}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny RX RQ}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{1}{\begin{sideways}{\tiny DONE}\end{sideways}}
  \bitbox{13}{\# of words (TX RQ)}
  \\
  \bitheader{0-15} \\
  \bitbox{2}{\tiny TX Dest}
  \bitbox{14}{Start word addr}
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah... I got hung up on the two page idea as I'd just made that change. It's obvious now, thanks.